# Struts 2 Date and JQuery UI Datepicker format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, struts2, datepicker

Im using Struts2 and JQuery UI. An entity has a `java.util.Date` property. It's value is from JQuery UI Datepicker. It works for me having `m/d/yy` format.

My concern are the following

- Is the format of date field in Struts2 need to be explicitly defined?
- If I have user from other Country, will the format automatically changed according?
- I set the format of JQuery UI Datepicker to `m/d/yy`. Is it okay or some users will have trouble with the date format?

Comment: on ui you can make use any format then in backend side again parse date to your required formate by creating proxy getter and setter

Answer (score 0):

You have to use localization feature for that.

```
<s:date name="date" format="%{getText('struts.date.format')}"/>
```

Also read about date tag
 http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/date.html

For Struts2 JQuery datepicker tag:

```
<sj:datepicker displayFormat="%{getText('jquery.date.format')}"/>
```

Comment: `date` tag is for output only, not for input.

Comment: It is just an example. If you need this for user input then you can use Struts2 JQuery datepicker tag `<sj:datepicker displayFormat="%{getText('jquery.date.format')}"/>`.